# Input Control to reply

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, input, do-while

I Wrote this code to ask the user if he wants to add money to his account , and I made a do while loop to
read the input if it is ("oui" or "non") and I made the variable rep to read the input from the user ,
Error : rep can not be resolved !

```
do {
    System.out.println("Souhaitez  vous ajoutez de l'argent ?");
    String rep = sc.nextLine();
} while (!rep.equals("Oui") || !rep.equals("Non"));
```

Comment: There are a lot of braces

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare rep outside of the loop put this

```
 String rep;
```

Above your loop and then inside do

```
rep = sc.nextLine();
```

In Java you can only once declare a variable with a type

```
String rep = "3";
String rep = "5";
```

Will lead to an compiler error *Duplicate local variable rep* and in your loop you are doing this. The other point is when you declare it inside the loop the while in the outer scope can not resolve it *rep cannot be resolved*.